# Cucumber java - cannot dected newly created step definiton

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-java

I took over existing cucumber java project. When I run existing tests from feature files everything runs smoothly, but when I am adding a new **phrase **in the feature file, Alt+Enter and 'Create step definition' and I am choosing the Steps file which is already used for other **phrases** in the same file,

[image]

I am running into this problem:

[image]

Can same have had the same problem ?

I've tried to

- create step definition via alt + enter or by pasting step definition method log from the logs
- update cucumber dependencies in my pom file

that's my run configuration:
I am adding new phrase into the APCIAM_DEV.feature and adding new step definition into the LabelJourneySteps

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the widget that creates the steps is broken. Have you tried doing it without IDE support?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I updated cucumber to the newer version, and every time when I am adding new feature implementation I need to run 'mvn test'  to make it works..

Comment: That sounds like your IDE is the problem. You'll have to ask JetBrains I guess.